# function of corr.test() and cor() to get pearson correlation and P value in R

Tags: r, correlation, p-value

I just tried to get a matrix to describe the P value and a matrix of correlation.

For example, I used the code below to create data

```
library(psych)
xx <- matrix(rnorm(16), 4, 4)
xx

     [,1]        [,2]       [,3]       [,4]
[1,] 1.2349830 -0.23417979 -1.0380279  0.2119736
[2,] 0.9540995  0.05405983  0.4438048  1.8375497
[3,] 0.1583041 -1.29936451 -0.6030342 -0.4052208
[4,] 0.4524374  1.03351913  1.3253830 -0.4829464
```

when I tried to run

```
corr.test(xx)
```

But I got the error as below:

```
Error in `row.names<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, value = value) : 
  duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed
In addition: Warning message:
non-unique value when setting 'row.names': ‘NA-NA’
```

But I thought I never set the row or column name before, and the row or column name could be NULL;I checked the row and column name with the code below:

```
> any(duplicated(colnames(xx)))
[1] FALSE
> any(duplicated(rownames(xx)))
[1] FALSE
```

However, I used the other correlation function cor() to get the matrix of correlation of xx:

```
co<-cor(xx)
       [,1]       [,2]        [,3]       [,4]
[1,]  1.0000000 0.24090246 -0.28707770 0.58664566
[2,]  0.2409025 1.00000000  0.79523833 0.06658293
[3,] -0.2870777 0.79523833  1.00000000 0.04730974
[4,]  0.5866457 0.06658293  0.04730974 1.00000000
```

Now, it works fine, and I thought maybe I can use the corr.p() to get the p value quickly. But actually, the I got the same error again!!

```
corr.p(co,16)
Error in `row.names<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, value = value) : 
 duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed
In addition: Warning message:
non-unique value when setting 'row.names': ‘NA-NA’
```

I am confused that I never set the rownames and colnames and have checked the  duplicate 'row.names' as well, but why I still got the error, did I missed any important point?

Comment: What are `corr.test` and `corr.p` functions? From which package(s) do they come from?

Comment: corr.test and corr.p come form the library("psych"), and the function of corr.test is to find the correlations, sample sizes, and probability values between elements of a matrix or data.frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(psych)

set.seed(123)
xx <- matrix(rnorm(16), 4, 4)
xx <- as.data.frame(xx)

out <- corr.test(xx)
print(out, short = FALSE)
# Call:corr.test(x = xx)
# Correlation matrix 
#       V1    V2    V3    V4
# V1  1.00 -0.02  0.96 -0.49
# V2 -0.02  1.00 -0.27 -0.75
# V3  0.96 -0.27  1.00 -0.22
# V4 -0.49 -0.75 -0.22  1.00
# Sample Size 
# [1] 4
# Probability values (Entries above the diagonal are adjusted for multiple tests.) 
#      V1   V2   V3 V4
# V1 0.00 1.00 0.25  1
# V2 0.98 0.00 1.00  1
# V3 0.04 0.73 0.00  1
# V4 0.51 0.25 0.78  0

#  To see confidence intervals of the correlations, print with the short=FALSE option

#  Confidence intervals based upon normal theory.  To get bootstrapped values, try cor.ci
#       lower     r upper    p
# V1-V2 -0.96 -0.02  0.96 0.98
# V1-V3 -0.04  0.96  1.00 0.04
# V1-V4 -0.99 -0.49  0.89 0.51
# V2-V3 -0.98 -0.27  0.93 0.73
# V2-V4 -0.99 -0.75  0.75 0.25
# V3-V4 -0.97 -0.22  0.94 0.78
```

Comment: This is not the correct function. This should be `corr.test`, not `cor.test`.

Comment: @Pascal corr.test is from which package?

Comment: Please read OP's answer to my question in the comments. But your solution seems to apply. Please edit

Comment: @Pascal is right, what I want to do is get the two tables, but not a specified value for two columns, the function of cor() can get a matrix of correlation value for any two columns, but without P value, but we also can use the function of corr.p() to get the p-value based on the correlation matrix we have got :)

Comment: You should completely revise your answer. It is quite unclear at the moment. Forget `cor.test` function.

Comment: thanks to@MLavoie, I used the code xx <- as.data.frame(xx) to change the format, and the function of corr.test(xx) works well now, but what if i still want to use the function of corr.p() to only get the P-value in this case, i still have the same above error ;(

Comment: @ZAWD  Now you have the p-values.

Comment: thanks @MLavoie, it looks good, but actually, it is possible to use the function of corr.p() to get the matrix of p value ?

Comment: or is it possible to save the the P value to a matrix ?

Comment: @ZAWD  They are in `out$p`.

Comment: @ZAWD  I think you get your answer now.\

Comment: But look at the p value matrix, I think the P value is still a bit strange, for example, the p (v2,v1) could be same as p (v1,v2) ,right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97302/discussion-between-zawd-and-pascal).

Comment: But look at the p value matrix, I think the P value is still a bit strange, for example, the p (v2,v1) could be same as p (v1,v2) ,right?

Comment: You now should ask the package maintainer `maintainer("psych")`.